# React App production build process and environment variables

Tags: reactjs, cicd, dev-to-production

I have a react app. For QA i will build my app, with QA .env variables, from git tag `QA-v1.0.0`, which are immutable and bundled into the application build. I will then have an image tagged as `QA-v1.0.0`.

When moving image `QA-v1.0.0` to production i will tag it as `v1.0.0`. I add a gke secret as a file for my production deployment with production env variables. However the QA variables are still embedded into the application and are not overridden.

Is the correct CICD process to move to production for react to rebuild my git tag `QA-v1.0.0` with production environment variables, create a new image of `v1.0.0` and continue deploy that to production?